# Cannot rosmake teleop_base, getting fatal error in Fuerte

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, teleop-base, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to rosmake teleop_base, I get the following error:
fatal error: joy/Joy.h: No such file or directory

I've got joy installed, why aren't I able to rosmkae teleop_base?  I'm running Fuerte.
Running "Rospack find joy" returns the following:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/joystick_drivers/joy

I tried redownloading teleop_base according this this site:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot
and have not have success.  What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40096/cannot-rosmake-teleop_base,-getting-fatal-error-in-fuerte/) by [breakspirit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2560/breakspirit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I've figured it out.  I included sensor_msgs/Joy to teleop_base.cpp.  That lead to several new errors.

In teleop_base.cpp, replace line 122 with   void joy_cb(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy_msg)
Anywhere that says joy_msg->get_axes_size() should be replaced with joy_msg->axes.size()
Anywhere that says joy_msg->get_buttons_size() should be replaced with joy_msg->buttons.size()

In teleop_base_keyboard.cpp, replace line 104 with boost::thread t = boost::thread(boost::bind(&TBK_Node::keyboardLoop, &tbk));

After that, teleop_base should succeed when running rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [breakspirit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2560/breakspirit/) with karma: 76 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KevinNickels](https://answers.ros.org/users/6631/kevinnickels/) on 2013-09-11**:
Thanks, this worked for me.  I also had to "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers" since the teleop_base has an unlisted dependency.

**Comment by [devesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4103/devesh/) on 2013-11-20**:
Thanks. All this worked for me. There were slight hiccups though.

1. It was line 121 for me, instead of line 122.
2. I was making the dumb mistake of not removing- '#include "joy/Joy.h"' line
3. Third dumb mistake was including "sensor_msg/Joy" instead of "sensor_msg/Joy.h"
4. KevinNickels comment.